Seliwanoff Test
Question:
Assertion (A): Ketoses give Seliwanoff's test faster than Aldoses
Reason (R): Ketoses undergo B-elimination followed by formation of furfural.
I know that ketoses give faster seliwanoff test than aldoses, and there is formation of furfural like intermediate in the reaction. But couldn't explain why Reason(R) is stated as false in the answer.

Is this a homework question? Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?] (https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)
